# What is the advantage of using scala pattern matching instead of java switch case?

Tags: java, scala, functional-programming, pattern-matching

Everybody says that pattern matching is a great feature in functional languages. Why?

Can't I simple use ifs and switch cases for everything?

I'd like to understand the advantages of using pattern matching instead of regular procedural programming ifs and switch cases

Comment: Might be better for http://programmers.stackexchange.com or even http://cs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic. Summary of my understanding - patterns give you much more flexibility to "match and deconstruct" in very compact form. Try to write `switch` case for something like "list of 3 elements where second is of particular type" in regular language...

Comment: I know this is glib, but… Scala's pattern matching is to Java's `switch` as an atomic bomb is to a hand grenade.

Comment: Hand grenade? I was thinking more along the lines of a paint bomb...

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I'd first like to note that you don't use pattern matching "instead" of switch statements.  Scala doesn't have `switch` statements, what it does have is match blocks, with cases inside that superficially look very similar to a switch statement.

Match blocks with pattern matching does everything that `switch` does, and much more.

**A) It's not restricted to just primitives and other types that Oracle have chosen to "bless" in the language spec** (Strings and Enums).  If you want to match on your own types, go right ahead!

**B) Pattern matching can also extract**.  For example, with a tuple:

```
val tup = ("hello world", 42)
tup match {
  case (s,i) =>
    println("the string was " + s)
    println("the number was " + i
}
```

With a list:

```
val xs = List(1,2,3,4,5,6)
xs match {
  case h :: t =>
    // h is the head: 1
    // t is the tail: 2,3,4,5,6
    // The :: above is also an example of matching with an INFIX TYPE
}
```

With a case class

```
case class Person(name: String, age: Int)
val p = Person("John Doe", 42)
p match {
  case Person(name, 42) =>
    //only extracting the name here, the match would fail if the age wasn't 42
    println(name)
}
```

**C) pattern matching can be used in value assignment and for-comprehensions**, not just in match blocks:

```
val tup = (19,73)

val (a,b) = tup

for((a,b) <- Some(tup)) yield a+b // Some(92)
```

**D) match blocks are expressions, not statements**

This means that they evaluate to the body of whichever case was matched, instead of acting entirely through side-effects.  This is crucial for functional programming!

```
val result = tup match { case (a,b) => a + b }
```

Comment: the "for ((a, b) <- tup) yield a + b" return error: value filter is not a member of (Int, Int)

Answer (score 6):

Somehow my edit/addition to @KevinWright answer got thrown away, so I'll add it here as one more nice pattern matching feature...

**F) Compiler exhaustiveness check of cases.**

If there exists a value matching against which will not be covered by existing cases compiler will warn you about it. This is a very nice feature of the language because if you don't ignore these compiler warnings you won't catch such runtime exceptions or come across a case you didn't think of. If you still run the application and ignore the warning you will get a nice descriptive exception if your value does not match any cases. Here is an illustration:

```
scala> def badMatch(l: List[Int]): Unit = l match { case x :: xs => println(x) }
<console>:7: warning: match may not be exhaustive.
It would fail on the following input: Nil
       def badMatch(l: List[Int]): Unit = l match { case x :: xs => println(x) }
                                          ^
badMatch: (l: List[Int])Unit

scala> badMatch(List(1, 2))
1

scala> badMatch(Nil)
scala.MatchError: List() (of class scala.collection.immutable.Nil$)
```

I prefer to get an exception in this case because it will fail loud and clear, and usually early instead of executing unexpected branches of logic.

If you use `if` you would have to use `else`, and if you use Java `switch` you would have to have `default` case to cover all cases. But notice the difference: Scala compiler knows that your empty list is different from non-empty list in this case, or in more broad sense you define the granularity of matches. You could match lists with 1 or 2 elements and ignore the rest, or use any other much more complex patterns without having to worry if you managed to cover all cases.

In short as you use complex extraction and matching logic compiler will make sure you didn't miss any cases. There is nothing similar in Java unless you use a default case like `default` or `else`.

Comment: Once your reputation gets high enough they turn you into a moderator and ask (bug?) you to review edits, so I can confirm that "adding to an existing answer" is a valid reason for rejecting edits.  There's also a lower level of reputation where your edits no longer need to be reviewed :)

Answer (score 3):

**pattern matching** is not somehow an alternative of **switch statement**, I consider it to be another way of doing **dynamic dispatch** in oop. They try to do the same thing: calling a different version of the function based on the dynamic type of the arguments

Comment: indeed quite close. I think pattern matching is a loaded concept - you can extract, match, etc in one shot. Since underneath is a partial function I like to think of pattern matching as of a partial function that takes args, checks if it can handle those (value domain) and optionally returns result of a block of code if function applies.

Comment: That's close, but dynamic dispatch can only cope with a single argument whereas pattern matching can cope with more than one. In OOP languages, if you want to consider two arguments, you need to use double dispatch http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_dispatch The University of Washington's 2nd Year Undergraduate Programming Languages has a good introduction to pattern matching with multiple arguments http://bit.ly/1xlGT4U and double dispatch http://bit.ly/1ETlo0U

Answer (score 2):

As it was written in the other answers, Scala pattern matching and Java switch do not make the same thing.

**switch statement:**

- Only works with native types, enumerated types, and the String class
- It is an alternative to a chain of "if-else" to create multiple execution paths, according to an imperative programming

**pattern matching:**

- It Allows to match on any sort of data with a first-match policy
- It meets a functional logic: each case statement returns a value and the whole match statement is virtually a function that returns the matching case value.

In other words, you can use the "pattern matching" for a similar purpose of the "java switch", but in doing so you're using functional tools in an imperative way.

Answer (score 0):

[JMPL](https://github.com/klappdev/jpml) is simple java library, which could emulate some of the features pattern matching, using Java 8 features.

```
      matches(data).as(
          new Person("man"),    () ->  System.out.println("man");
          new Person("woman"),  () ->  System.out.println("woman");
          new Person("child"),  () ->  System.out.println("child");        
          Null.class,           () ->  System.out.println("Null value "),
          Else.class,           () ->  System.out.println("Default value: " + data)
       );


       matches(data).as(
          Integer.class, i  -> { System.out.println(i * i); },
          Byte.class,    b  -> { System.out.println(b * b); },
          Long.class,    l  -> { System.out.println(l * l); },
          String.class,  s  -> { System.out.println(s * s); },
          Null.class,    () -> { System.out.println("Null value "); },
          Else.class,    () -> { System.out.println("Default value: " + data); }
       );

       matches(figure).as(
          Rectangle.class, (int w, int h) -> System.out.println("square: " + (w * h)),
          Circle.class,    (int r)        -> System.out.println("square: " + (2 * Math.PI * r)),
          Else.class,      ()             -> System.out.println("Default square: " + 0)
       );
```

Answer (score 0):

Taken from a great book [Programming in Scala](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0997148004) by Martin Odersky (creator of Scala) and others.

Java's `switch`

- integer-type, enum and constants can be used can be used in `case`
- `break` at the end of each alternative
- fall through from one alternative to the next without `break`
- **doesn't result in a value**

Scala's `match`

- any kind of constant, as well as other things, can be used in `case`
- no `break` at the end of each alternative
- no fall through from one alternative to the next
- **results in a value**

---

**Exampes** of the same logic programmed in Java and Scala:

Scala

```scala
firstArg match
  case "salt" => println("pepper")
  case "chips" => println("salsa")
  case "eggs" => println("bacon")
  case _ => println("huh?")
```

Java

```java
switch (firstArg) {
  case "salt":
    System.out.println("pepper");
    break;
  case "chips":
    System.out.println("salsa");
    break;
  case "eggs":
    System.out.println("bacon");
    break;
  default:
    System.out.println("huh?");
}
```

---

Scala's `match` can **results in a value**, Java's `switch` cannot:

```scala
friend match
  case "salt" => "pepper"
  case "chips" => "salsa"
  case "eggs" => "bacona"
  case _ => "huh?"
```