# Pattern matching: advantage over switch-case?

Tags: pattern-matching, elixir

I'm learning Elixir, and can't see the advantage of pattern matching over good ol' switch case. What am I missing?

Comment: Different language, same question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21355060/what-is-the-advantage-of-using-scala-pattern-matching-instead-of-java-switch-cas

Answer (score 7):

In short, Elixir's pattern matching `case` will make you **focus on the shape of your data**. Instead of allowing just about any expressions in the language, and looking for a true condition, you show the reader what shapes in your data that are important to consider. It is more intention revealing.

Elixir has both `case` and `cond`. The former takes a value and runs different pattern matches on it. The latter doesn't take a value, but will instead evaluate some expressions until it finds one that's truthy. A `cond` works like `if … elseif … else`.

```
list = [3,2,1]
string = "abc"

case list do
  []        -> :empty             # won't match
  [1 | t]   -> :starts_with_one   # won't match
  [3, b, c] -> "3, #{b} and #{c}" # match!
  _         -> :fallback          # _ would match anything
end

cond do
  List.last(list) == 2     -> :two_at_the_end # false
  length(string) == 3      -> :three_letters  # true
  true                     -> :fallback
end
```

As you see, there's really nothing that connects the expression in `cond`. They don't have to act on the same data. You can also use expressions that are not allowed in pattern matching. Both these aspects make `cond` very flexible, but it also is kind of a code smell. There's **no coherence** to the block. Expressions can have **side-effects**. I need to look more carefully at a `cond` than a `case`.

In contrast, the `case` expression let's me very explicitly reason about the shape of my data. All the matching is done on the same data, so it has a natural cohesion. It tells a reader a lot about the author's expectations on some data. It's very **intention revealing**. It quickly shows the shapes the author expect the data to take, and any special cases that should be treated differently. When reading a `case` statement, you too can focus on the data.

Pattern matching also let you capture parts of the pattern. I capture the second and third list element in the matching pattern. They are only available inside the `case` block and won't "leak" out.

The restricted set of expressions allowed in a pattern match also means it's generally very fast.

Answer (score 0):

A case statement is actually pattern matching. Each match in the case statement is a match and can be used to extract segments of the match. Furthermore, it supports guards. For example:

```
case my_map do
  %{type: 1, data_for_1: data} -> "Data 1 is %{data}"
  %{type: 2, data_for_2: data} => "Data 2 is %{data}"
  map -> "No matching type found: %{inspect map}"
end
```

Now, perhaps you meant to ask, what is the advantage of using case over multiple function heads?

In this case, its a matter of style/preference. However, it does reduce the size of your function. I much prefer the multiple function cause approach, especially if each code block is large.