# Switch/Case - When we can expect switch operator rework?

Tags: dart

Hope Dart devs will add range of values and range checking in switch/case operators -
check if value is in range, check array elements, check multiple variables with same switch operator:

```
int i=27;
switch (i) {
    case 1..30:
    break;
    default:
}

List<int> a=[1,5,7,14,25,30];
switch (a) {
  case a.contains(5):
  break;
  case a[1..4]>0:
  break;
}

switch ([a,i]) {
  case i==5:
  case a[1..4]>0:
  break;
  case a[i] is int:
  break;
}
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's calling for speculation about future pans of a language, not an actual programming issue. It's both opinion based and impossible to answer.

Answer (score 0):

You're asking for something akin to [pattern matching in C#](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-7#pattern-matching). This isn't the place to be posting about your hopes for Dart's future. StackOverflow is a place to post issues you're having so that other people can help with specific answers.

That said, here's the situation. The Dart team has a lot on their plate for their roadmap across the various [upcoming versions of Dart](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/milestones), and though I haven't looked through every post, I didn't see pattern matching among them. And if I'm to be perfectly honest here, I'd agree that pattern matching isn't nearly high enough a priority for them to focus on it at the expense of other features like, for instance, bringing nullable variables to full release.

If I were in the Dart team's shoes and I saw this proposal, I would ask how this feature benefits the language. What problems or inadequacies exist in the language that would be solved by pattern matching? Just about any application of a switch block with pattern matching could also be done with a series of if blocks:

Switch with pattern matching:

```dart
dynamic obj;
switch (obj) {
  case obj == null:
    print('obj is null');
    break;
  case obj is List:
    print('length of obj is ${obj.length}');
    break;
  case obj is num && obj >= 5:
    print('obj is greater than 5');
    break;
  default:
    print('obj didn't match any conditions');
    break;
}
```

If blocks:

```dart
dynamic obj;
if (obj == null) {
  print('obj is null');
} else if (obj is List) {
  print('length of obj is ${obj.length}');
} else if (obj is num && obj >= 5) {
  print('obj is greater than 5');
} else {
  print('obj didn't match any conditions');
}
```

(To put an even finer point on it, the if block approach results in fewer lines. What's more, the switch block requires a fair amount of boilerplate since each `case` or `default` requires a `break` statement.)

What's more, there isn't going to be any performance benefit, either. A switch block typically works like a hash table, reaching the desired code in O(1) constant time. However, this isn't possible with pattern matching, so in order to support this, languages with pattern matching support tend to pre-compile the match statement into something else entirely, thus losing the performance benefit of the hash table. This is evident in C# where pattern matching in a switch block is merely syntactic sugar for the equivalent set of if statements. (I'm not going to paste an example of it here because A] it's beside the point and B] it's too long, so you're going to have to trust me on this.)

So yeah, the only benefit to having this feature would be some subjective readability, and that's not nearly enough to justify it being a top priority addition to the language.

Now **that** being said, this is something that has been discussed [here](https://groups.google.com/a/dartlang.org/forum/#!topic/misc/MJXLjFxZu0A), [here](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/2949), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21355060/what-is-the-advantage-of-using-scala-pattern-matching-instead-of-java-switch-cas/21355296#21355296). Pattern matching could have some usefulness when paired with other language features, such as first-class tuples and object destructuring. Unfortunately, Dart doesn't have many of those features either, and if we're talking about which features would benefit more, I would definitely rather have those features first.

**TL;DR - Probably not any time soon.**